# Verifying solution: Twelve fair coins are flipped

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations

I need to know if I did this problem correctly or incorrectly.

Twelve fair coins are flipped.

(a) What is the expected number of heads that will be obtained?

**if a coin is tossed 12 times, the maximum probability of getting heads is 12.**

(b) What is the variance in the expected number of heads?

**E[X]= (1)*(1/2)+(2)*(1/2)+(3)*(1/2)+(4)*(1/2)+(5)*(1/2)+(6)*(1/2)+(7)*(1/2)+(8)*(1/2)+(9)*(1/2)+(10)*(1/2)+(11)*(1/2)+(12)*(1/2) = 39**

**E[X^2]= (1)^2*(1/2)+(2)^2*(1/2)+(3)^2*(1/2)+(4)^2*(1/2)+(5)^2*(1/2)+(6)^2*(1/2)+(7)^2*(1/2)+(8)^2*(1/2)+(9)^2*(1/2)+(10)^2*(1/2)+(11)^2*(1/2)+(12)^2*(1/2) = 325**

**Var(X)=(E[X^2]-µ^2)= 325-(39)^2= 325-1521 = -1196**

Comment: Sorry...out of $12$ tosses you expect to get $39$ Heads?

Comment: negative variance ... ugh, can't unsee

Comment: And you think the variance is negative?  I think you should review the basic properties of average and variance.

Comment: The maximum probability of getting head is 12? Probabilities must be between 0 and 1.

Comment: "*What is the expected number of heads that will be obtained? ... if a coin is tossed 12 times, the maximum probability of getting heads is 12*"  You are using words in very incorrect ways.  It makes me think you do not actually know what those words mean.  You mean to say *if a coin is tossed 12 times, the maximum* **number of heads** *possible is 12.*  This, however, has very little to do with the problem of finding the expected number of heads that you will see.

Comment: What is the correct approach to solving this problem?

Comment: As for your calculation for $E[X]$... you seem to be under the mistaken assumption that there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability that there is exactly one head observed, also a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability that there are exactly two heads observed, etc... on up to a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ that twelve heads are observed.  This should be painfully obvious that it is incorrect since these are disjoint events and the sum of their probabilities is greater than $1$, an impossibility.  Try again to find the probability of exactly one head, the probability of exactly two heads, etc... its not 1/2.

Comment: I suggest going back to the definitions.  And start with a simpler problem.  Suppose you only throw the coin one time, can you do it in that case?  What about $2$ times?  For small numbers you can write everything out explicitly.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to go back to definitions, and do this the long boring rigorous mathematical way, however you should know from experience that "about half" of the coins flipped will show heads, that is to say if we flip 12 coins we expect about 6 of them to be heads on average.  If you do this with a rigorous math proof you will indeed verify this result formally.

Comment: The approach I would recommend is to find the expectation and variance for a single coin, as my starting point, and then look for a rule as to how those numbers might scale if you added a second or 3rd (or 12th) coin.

Comment: I would start with this basic tutorial: https://math.tutorvista.com/statistics/coin-toss-probability.html

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted answers are incorrect and should be obvious that they are incorrect for a number of reasons.  Think about what it is saying.  "*If I flip 12 coins, I expect around 39 of those coins to be heads*" can't be true.  Further, variances are *never* negative numbers.

**Hint:**

This follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

The probability of getting exactly $k$ heads in your experiment is instead $$Pr(X=k)=\binom{12}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{12-k}$$

Use this to properly calculate the correct probabilities for $X$ to be equal to $0,1,2,\dots,12$ and fix your calculations for $E[X]$ and later for $E[X^2]$.

> $E[X] = 0\times Pr(X=0)+1\times Pr(X=1)+2\times Pr(X=2)+\dots+12\times Pr(X=12)$, you incorrectly filled in $\frac{1}{2}$ for each of these probabilities.

---

*Alternate solution hint:*

You could approach via indicator variables quite easily by noting that the random variable $X$ which counts the total number of heads is the sum of indicator variables $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots,X_{12}$ where $X_i$ is a random variable which takes the value of $0$ if the $i$'th coin is a tail and $1$ if the $i$'th coin is a head.  From there you can use linearity of expectation for an almost immediate solution.

> $E[X] = E[X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots+X_{12}]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots+E[X_{12}]$ and note that $E[X_1]=Pr(X_1=1)$ is simply the probability that the first coin is a head.  Similarly for the others.